# Above a certain amount product will be cheaper

Tags: product, price

I need that if the buyer buys more than for ex **(200)** of **one** product from **(201)**, he will pay cheaper the product. I explain till item **(200)** he will pay **2 dollars** and from item **(201)** he will pay **1 dollar**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a Magento version, so I'll use Magento 1.14/1.9 as the basis of my answer; though, the same thing could be created for Magento 2.

Sounds like you want to use customer segmentation and a custom price rule for that segment.

Basically you would create a customer segment with the condition like:

[image: Customer segment conditions]

Then you'd create a Shopping Cart Price Rule and specify the condition to be the customer segment you created:

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule conditions]

Then just specify the product discount in the "Actions" tab.

The only downside is that the price won't change until it's in the cart.  Otherwise, you'll need a custom module to add customer segments as a possible condition for Catalog Price Rules, or the module will have to change the price on its own based on customer segment.

Comment: i dont understand i need that only  the products above 200 should be at a discounted price